# SHELL to TXT, Is It Possible?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, linux-mint

I created a .sh file in Linux Server and would like to convert it into a text  file for windows or Linux mint. Is that possible of doing?

Thank You!!!

Comment: All shell scripts already are text files. What kind of conversion do you think is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

In windows right click on it and click "Open with..." and choose notepad.

In mint go to terminal and use either vi or nano to edit the file:

```
vi /path/to/file/file.sh
```

Comment: Notepad (or at least, many releases of it) won't handle UNIX line endings correctly -- might suggest a different tool for Windows. IIRC, wordpad handles them fine on import.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure if it is what you wanted, but if you have i.e. file named script.sh, you can simply redirect it to another file by executing

```
cat script.sh > script.txt
```

However, be aware that EOF in linux is different than in Windows, so you can use [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/convert-ctrlm-carriage-return-between-unix-windows-textfiles/).

Comment: `cp script.sh script.txt` would be a more natural way of expressing this operation I think.

Answer (score 0):

just copy the contents from sh file into another file within linux or run this command

```
cp file.sh file.txt
```